# C# to VB.Net conversion assistance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have the the following C# code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedDropDownListFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, IEnumerable<ExtendedSelectListItem> selectList, string optionLabel, object htmlAttributes)
{
    return SelectInternal(htmlHelper, optionLabel, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), selectList, false /* allowMultiple */, HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
}
```

I am struggling with a VB conversion of this and was wondering if someone could assist. Specifically, the line in the function signature:

```
Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad fellow members, it was a namespace issue.

I just needed to add an imports:

```
Imports System.Linq.Expressions
```

I guess I should have dug in a little deeper before I asked. :(

Comment: Sometimes formulating the question helps to identify the true source of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
expression As Expression(Of Func(Of TModel, TProperty))
```